# Django Rest Framework - return user id and token after registration

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I try to register user and return token and user id. Doing it like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework import status
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class CreateUser(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=serializer.instance)
        user = User.objects.filter(user=serializer.instance)
        return Response({'token': token.key, 'id':user.id}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

And I get an error

```
Cannot resolve keyword "user" into field. Choices are: auth_token, date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, user_permissions, username
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mistake is in the line

```
user = User.objects.filter(user=serializer.instance)
```

Firstly, there is no field named `user` on your `User` model. Secondly, you don't need to filter on the `User` model to get the created user as you already have the user with you in `serializer.instance`.  So, there is no need for that line.

If you just want the `id`, you can get that using `serializer.instance.id`.

Answer (score 1):

A neater solution is to depend on `super()`'s implementation:

```
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user_id=response.data["id"])
        response.data["token"] = str(token)
        return response
```

And ensure `"id"` is included in your Serializer's fields:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["id", ...
```