# return token after registration with django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm using django-rest-framework-simplejwt and was wondering if it's possible to return a token after registering a user?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622616/django-rest-framework-return-auth-token-after-registration) post has a solution for another jwt package and I was wondering how I could do something similar for simplejwt?

thanks

Comment: Did you tried anything so far?

Comment: Of course it is possible. But as @JPG already said, have you tried anything ? writing complete solution is not what SO is for. So I'd suggest you to try and if you hit something which you cannot solve, ask the question.

Comment: Unfortunately unlike django-rest-framework-jwt, there is no method documented for simplejwt. Right now I'm looking through the source code to see how it may be possible.

Answer (score 8):

I just solved my own question. Let me know if you have any comments. Thanks!

## serializers.py

```
class RegisterUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for creating user objects."""

    tokens = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('id', 'password', 'email', 'tokens')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def get_tokens(self, user):
        tokens = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        refresh = text_type(tokens)
        access = text_type(tokens.access_token)
        data = {
            "refresh": refresh,
            "access": access
        }
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = models.User(
            email=validated_data['email']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()    
        return user
```

views.py

```
class UserListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """Handles creating and listing Users."""
    queryset = User.objects.all()

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = RegisterUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            self.perform_create(serializer)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Can you tell how to import RefreshToken ? and your using django-rest-framework-simplejwt right?

Comment: from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

Comment: text_type is not defined

Comment: @shoaibkhan, replace text_type() to str()

Comment: This worked for me, agree a custom attribute with serializers.SerializerMethodField() and use function get_field and works.

Answer (score 4):

another possible solution is:

in your view

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import AccessToken, RefreshToken


@login_required
def index(request):
    tokenr = TokenObtainPairSerializer().get_token(request.user)  
    tokena = AccessToken().for_user(request.user)
    return render(request,'myview/index.html', {"refresh" : str(tokenr),"access" : str(tokena)} )
```

I used @login_required just to be sure we have a request.user authenticated, but you could pass a dict instead

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can do something like this :

```
def custom_registration_view(request):
    //code to validate & register your user
    payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
    return HttpResponse(jwt_encode_handler(payload), 201)
```

The payload_handler, encode_handler and decode_handler you can specify in settings file.