# How to store simplejwt token into database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm using django-rest-framework-simplejwt for user registration.

Following this tutorial [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033003/return-token-after-registration-with-django-rest-framework-simplejwt)

I code like following:

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True,
    )
    password2 = serializers.CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'},max_length=20
    )
    tokens = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'password2', 'tokens']

    def get_tokens(self, user):
        user = UserProfile(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],
            username=self.validated_data['username']
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match.'})
        user.set_password(password)
        tokens = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        refresh = text_type(tokens)
        access = text_type(tokens.access_token)
        data = {
            "refresh": refresh,
            "access": access
        }
        return data

    def save(self):
        user = UserProfile(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],
            username=self.validated_data['username']
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match.'})
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

in view:

```
class UserCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    '''create user'''
    serializer_class = RegistrationSerializer
```

The problem is each time I create a user,I can get the return of the 2 two tokens,however in data base I can't find the token.

So I guess I didn't store them,so should I store the token?

Answer (score 3):

JWT can be used for database-less authentication. because it encodes data needed for authentication in tokens. Your app will be able to authenticate users after decoding tokens with data embedded in it.

But if you want to store tokens in `simplejwt` you can use `OutstandingingToken` model which is implemented in `simplejwt` to store tokens in database.

Before using `OutstandingToken`, make sure you put `rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` list of your project settings.

Comment: nice solution Milad , thank you !
damet garm.